wifi driver for Macbook Pro 2010 on debian 12: wlp2s0 state DORMANT and cannot wifi scan
I installed Debian 12 on my MacBook Pro 2010 using a netinst image and an internet connection through the Ethernet adapter. Following the instructions on the Debian wiki for wireless LAN (WL), I installed the kernel module for BCM4322.
Now, NetworkManager is recognizing the Wi-Fi interface, but when I try to scan for networks, it doesn't return any results. The interface wlp2s0 is displayed with the state 'DORMANT', and I'm unable to bring it up or change its state to 'DEFAULT'
from dmesg i see
    wlan0: Broadcom BCM432 802.11 Hybrid wireless controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
...
    wlp2s0 scan_result error (-22)

Eventually I realized that the wlp2s0 interface only becomes ready after putting the MacBook to sleep and waking it up. At that point, the WiFi scan works, and the interface connects. Why isn't the wlp2s0 immediately available after a normal boot, and what should I try to do ?
Can someone explain how to figure out what's wrong with my 2010 MacBook in relation to Debian 12?

Error 22 is used to indicate "invalid argument". Check your configuration

After a restart, I was able to do a scan and see the list and connect to WiFi, but after the next restart, everything disappeared.
